# Randomly Linux freezing on Acer Extensa

Tags: linux, freeze

On my Debian and Arch keeps freezing randomly won't respond at all with keyboard, mouse or power button. I have to over ride by holding power button for 10 seconds to hard reset. I boot linux using EFI.

I can't nothing see in logs for the incident.

I've tried different possibilities that I read from different forums:

- "Windows Trick" - boot to windows, log in and restart
- "Kernel flag" - add to the kernel boot flags 'reboot = bios'

Unfortunately, nothing works.
On Windows I have no problems with freezing.

My Notebook: Acer Extensa 2508-C3N6

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output of `dmesg` after a freeze? With luck you will find the origin of the problem.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not show anything unusual.